# controlling a remote machine

Tags: controls

I want to develop some kind of automation system i can control some pcs in my network.Features i am looking to develop are as follows:
1)Ability to establish a connection with some remote systems and executing some commands on those
2)Ability to transfer files from main controller pc to those pcs
3)Ability to get status of other pc

I dont want to install some explicit server on each of the client machines , and want to use some in built protocol /services running on windows a my clinets are windows.

The only this available with my controller pc is  Administator user name and passwd and clinet machine ips.

IBM TPM uses some port to do such things but am not usre which protocal /service it uses?
I have done a remote software installation using ibm tpm.I dont think it uses telnet or ssh.

Which inbuilt service/protocol i should use? (not telnet or ssh)

```
I need to design a tool that can install software on remote client machine.
Basically i need Deploy MSI, EXE, BAT etc. on various client machines without user interaction.
```

There are lots of tool on net that provide these features but i need to develop such type of utility.

Please suggest

Comment: What will you be developing this in?

Answer (score 1):

you can setup remote desktop on the machines.

Comment: i want to automate software installtion on client machines without user interation , so cant use remote desktop

Answer (score 0):

For Establishing command : you can setup remote desktop

For transferring files: You can map drives of other machines programmatically using the method WNetAddConnection2().
Its unmanaged code ...
This might help :
http://vbnet.mvps.org/index.html?code/network/wnetaddconnection2.htm
http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/mpr/wnetaddconnection2.html